# JS For loop with conditionals

Tags: javascript

I've got a function with a For loop that will count from 0 to the value of n, but, will include a string instead of an integer when it reaches numbers that are either multiples of 5 or 7. The problem is it only shows 1 output and I want it to list the append the outputs on each iteration. ( 1 
, 2 
, 3 
, 4 
, etc.).

HTML:

```
<button onclick="callit()">Call OneTwo</button>
<div id="OneTwo">Test</div>
```

JS:

```
            function callit() {
                x = 0;
                n = 100;
                z = "The number is " + x + "<br>";
                one = "One";
                two = "Two";
                ot = one + " " + two;
                obj = document.getElementById('OneTwo');

                for (x; x <= n; x++) {
                    if ((x % 5) === 0) {
                        z = one;
                    }
                    if ((x % 7) === 0) {
                        z = two;
                    }
                    if (((x % 3) === 0) && ((x % 5) === 0)) {
                        z = ot;
                    }
                    obj.innerHTML = z;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, this should do what you are looking for:

```
obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + "<br />" + z;
```

You need to maintain the value of innerHTML instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are replacing whole html of div with current value. You need to append it. Try following:

```
obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + '<br/>' + z;
```

[<kbd>jsfiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/Adwje/)

Comment: i hope, this wont solve his problem... you can give this as an comment.

Comment: Yeah I know it's replace the HTML instead of appending the iteration, but it still doesn't work with this.

Comment: Need a `+` between `obj.innerHTML` and `'<br/>'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the previous value and append with the new one. You had just append on existing one, which makes the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function callit() {
                x = 0;
                n = 100;
                z = "The number is " + x + "<br>";
                one = "One";
                two = "Two";
                ot = one + " " + two;
                obj = document.getElementById('OneTwo');

                for (x; x <= n; x++) {
                    if ((x % 5) === 0) {
                        z = one;
                    }
                    if ((x % 7) === 0) {
                        z = two;
                    }
                    if (((x % 3) === 0) && ((x % 5) === 0)) {
                        z = ot;
                    }
                   obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + "<br />" + z;
                }
            }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="callit()">Call OneTwo</button>
<div id="OneTwo">Test</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Come on seriously?  Just a block of code with ZERO explanation.

Comment: This does help as far as posting each iteration goes, now the outputs aren't giving the desired numbers, but I just added else lines for each condition which works.